# Wrong image dimensions in OpenCV when converting color spaces

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pytorch, color-space

I have 2 identical arrays, one obtained by simply reading the image and using

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
array_1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
```

and other by

```
from torchvision import transforms
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Lambda(lambda img: cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda img: np.array(img)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
])

img_scaled = img * 1./255
img_lab_norm = transform(img).permute(1,2,0).numpy()
array_2 = (((img_lab_norm + 1) / 2)*255).astype(np.int)
img_rec_norm = cv2.cvtColor(array_2, cv2.COLOR_Lab2RGB)
```

For some reason in the `cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_Lab2RGB)` line `array_1` works and `array_2` throws this error

```
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)
```

Doing `(array_2 == array_1).all()` returns `True`
I have no idea why OpenCV treats `array_2` like it has 4 dimensions.

Comment: Dimensions are fine, the datatype is wrong. For some reason you cast it to `np.int` on the line above the `cvtColor`.

Comment: I tried both with floats and ints and both give the same error. I cast it to int as it's in 0-255 range and per matplotlib `Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)`

Comment: 0..255 means a byte, aka 8 bit unsigned integer -- `np.uint8`.

Comment: You were right I confused those two and it solved my problem, thank you for further advice.